# raspistill does not capture any images, when it run by cron

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi, cron

i have a problem with crontab in linux, exec function in php, and raspistill function in raspberry pi. I am new with raspberry pi, linux, and cron.

So i want to make an automation for submit token, which there are step, the raspberry capture the token automatically.
The problem is when i run the script with cron , i did not get any image. But if i just run the script without cron , it works perfectly.

I run cron every 3 minute to run my php script.

my crontab script : `*/3 * * * * sudo php /var/www/html/raspbank/index.php`

i am using php script [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to run raspistill , both of them works also if i run without cron.

the command is : `exec(sudo raspistill -w 1024 -h 720 -o images/capturedImage);`

if anyone has a solution please let me know :) thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is still relevant to you. But I used a relative path in the bash script as output parameter for raspistill. So the image was being saved, but not in the correct location. Hope this helps.

Comment: I had the same problem as the poster, and this solved the problem for me